# asp.net mvc 5 dropdownlist not showing item in list just after adding it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cascadingdropdown

What I'm trying to do...
I am trying to get a newly added item to display in a cascading dropdownlist.

Overview...
The first dropdownlist (I'll call it ddlCategory) is for selecting a Category of electrical devices (ie. Appliances, Audio-Visual, Lighting, etc.). The second dropdownlist (I'll call ddlElecDev) is populated with the devices which are filtered by the selected Category. If the device isn't listed in ddlElecDev then the user can click a link to add a new one. After saving the newly added electrical device, the user is redirected back to the original page with the electrical device id as a parameter.

All the above seems to work fine. However, when the user is redirected to the first page, not only is the newly added electrical device not selected in ddlElecDev, but it doesn't even appear in the list. Strangely, if I refresh the page, it ***is*** automatically selected.

Can anyone explain to me how to get the newly added device to be selected without having to refresh the page?

Here's the markup for selecting the category and electrical device:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories, "Select a Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ElectricalDeviceID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.CascadingDropDownListFor(
                expression: model => model.ElectricalDeviceID,
                triggeredByProperty: model => model.SelectedCategory,
                url: Url.Action("GetElectricalDevices", "ElectricalDeviceConfigurations"),
                ajaxActionParamName: "categoryId",
                optionLabel: "Select an Electrical Device",
                disabledWhenParrentNotSelected: false,
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElectricalDeviceID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Not Listed? Add a new Electrical Device", "AddNew", "ElectricalDevices", new { returnUrl = string.Format("/ElectricalDeviceConfigurations/AddConfiguration?eventVendorId={0}", Model.EventVendorID) }, null)
            </div>
        </div>
```

The documentation for the Cascading DropDownList Helper can be found at 
https://github.com/alexanderar/Mvc.CascadeDropDown

Here's the Controller method for selecting the Electrical Device:

```
public ActionResult AddConfiguration(int? eventVendorId, int? newElecDev)
        {
(Some code removed for brevity)
            var selectedCategoryId = db.ElectricalDeviceCategoryLookups.Where(cat => cat.Category == Enums.ElectricalDeviceCategory.All).FirstOrDefault().ID;
            var electricalDeviceID = (newElecDev.HasValue) ? newElecDev : null;
            return View(new ElecDevConfigSelectionViewModel { EventVendorID = eventVendorId, EventVendor = eventVendor, Categories = GetCategories(), SelectedCategory = selectedCategoryId, ElectricalDeviceID = electricalDeviceID });
        }
```

Here's the controller methods for populating the Categories and the Electrical Devices:

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
        {
            var categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
            db.ElectricalDeviceCategoryLookups.OrderBy(c => c.Description).ToList().ForEach(item => categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Description, Value = item.ID.ToString() } ));
            return categories;
        }

        public ActionResult GetElectricalDevices(int? categoryId)
        {
            if (categoryId.HasValue)
            {
                var selCategory = db.ElectricalDeviceCategoryLookups.Where(cat => cat.ID == categoryId).FirstOrDefault().Category;
                var elecDevicesSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                var elecDevices = (selCategory == Enums.ElectricalDeviceCategory.All) ? db.ElectricalDevices.OrderBy(ed => ed.Name).ToList() : db.ElectricalDevices.Where(ed => ed.Category == selCategory).OrderBy(ed => ed.Name).ToList();
                elecDevices.ForEach(ed => elecDevicesSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = ed.Name, Value = ed.ID.ToString() }));
                return Json(elecDevicesSelectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here's the View Model:

```
public class ElecDevConfigSelectionViewModel
    {
        public int? EventVendorID { get; set; }
        public EventVendor EventVendor { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public int SelectedCategory { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Electrical Device")]
        public int? ElectricalDeviceID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the controller methods for adding a new electrical device:

```
// GET: ElectricalDevices/AddNew
        public ActionResult AddNew(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            var selectedCategoryId = db.ElectricalDeviceCategoryLookups.FirstOrDefault().ID;
            return View(new AddNewElectricalDeviceViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, Categories = GetCategories(), SelectedCategory = null });
        }

        // POST: ElectricalDevices/AddNew
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddNew(AddNewElectricalDeviceViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var selectedCategory = db.ElectricalDeviceCategoryLookups.Find(model.SelectedCategory);
                var electricalDevice = new ElectricalDevice 
                { 
                    Name = model.ElectricalDevice.Name, 
                    Description = model.ElectricalDevice.Description, 
                    Category = selectedCategory.Category, 
                    Wattage = model.ElectricalDevice.Wattage 
                };
                db.ElectricalDevices.Add(electricalDevice);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var returnUrl = string.Format("{0}&newElecDev={1}", model.ReturnUrl, electricalDevice.ID);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Here's the View Model for adding a new electrical device:

```
public class AddNewElectricalDeviceViewModel
    {
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public int? SelectedCategory { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
        public ElectricalDevice ElectricalDevice { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Browser caching ? What if you add a random unique string to the end of url before redirecting ?

Comment: Thanks Shyju, but I thought that was what I'm doing by these lines from the AddNew method in the controller: 'var returnUrl = string.Format("{0}&newElecDev={1}", model.ReturnUrl, electricalDevice.ID);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);'  Did you have something else in mind?